# Is there any way to compare different types of weapons?

Tags: far-cry-3

In the store, you have a "compare" function.  But is it possible to compare different type of weapons ?  For instance, is it possible to compare a SMG to a rifle ?  Or a signature weapon with any other weapon ?

[image]

Comment: I'm almost positive you can't.  I will do some playing around with it tonight.

Comment: Ok :(  Not really convenient...

Comment: Agreed.  I think they are trying to imply that assault rifles have more damage, and accuracy, but less fire rate and mobility.   While  it is the opposite for smgs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it simply looks like it's a missing (or buggy) feature: you won't be able to compare weapons from different categories.  As soon as you leave a category to switch to another one, you simply loose your "compare" marker.

There are a few weapons guides on the web (e.g. [this one from ING](http://www.ign.com/wikis/far-cry-3/Weapons_and_Equipment)), but I couldn't find one with the possibility to compare weapons.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's this site I found it's not perfect but you can compare weapons much more easily with less hassle than the slow menus in far cry 3. Or just open an extra tab in your browser. http://www.farcryweapons.com/farcry3/